# SNMP monitoring tool(s) for full network monitoring with hookable alerting/notifications

Tags: monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a full network monitoring tool that is able to understand the SNMP protocol (for MySQL), preferably an open-source solution.  We specifically want to be able to hook into the alerting mechanism so we can have it forward alerts and notifications to our internal logging and alerting tools.  Are there any suggestions?

The number of machines that we have to monitor is on the order of 50 or so.

We could write our own handler for the SNMP protocol to do this, but it would be nice to have it integrated with an existing full-fledged system.

P.S. Apparently MySQL doesn't have built-in SNMP support as I originally thought, so most tools that do this are plug-ins that inspect MySQL's statistics.

Comment: I recommend to use http://alert-grid.com as an alerting service, anyway it cannot monitor your infrastructure itselfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three open-source solutions that I can recommend are the following:

http://www.opennms.org/ 
http://www.nagios.org/ 
http://www.zenoss.com/

With all three, you can hook into the alerting systems and decide how you want to handle alerts and notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't an open-source solution, PathSolutions (www.pathsolutions.com) is an excellent option for Network and VoIP monitoring.  Concerning alerting my company, Telizent Communications (www.telizent.com), has an excellent solution for unifying alerting systems into a "single pane of glass".  To learn more check out AlarmSync at http://telizent.com/EnterpriseMonitoringandManagment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Net-SNMP is open source and starting with version 5.5 it provides the ability to log notifications into a mysql database.  See the README.sql file for details.